# Seeking Consumer API Endpoint for Gender, RDC, BillPayFlag, ChgoffFlag, and Branch Information

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

I find information that we need, i.e. Gender, RDC, BillPayFlag, ChgoffFlag, Branch, about consumer users that /a/mobile/api/v0/institutions/{institutionId}/users/{userId}/details endpoint returns. But this seems to be an Admin API endpoint.

Do we have a consumer API endpoint that returns this information - Gender, RDC, BillPayFlag, ChgoffFlag, Branch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there isn't any equivalent in the *Consumer API*.

As you've gathered, the [Admin API - Consumer - User Details](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/api-reference/v0/consumers/details/) is probably your best bet.

Comment: Thanks, @Jaime for the clarification. What is the procedure for an FI to permit us, the plugin developers, to access the Admin API?

Comment: It's a _separate_ set of API credentials for the Admin API. Also, the typical auth model uses the Client Credentials Flow (which is OAuth, but _different_ from the Authorization Code Flow). I'd suggest getting familiar with https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/getting-started/ and getting familiar with the Admin API concepts. This quickstart is also good to capture the main steps: https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/admin-api/quickstarts/authentication/